# Best practice for UIKeyboard notifications - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikeyboard

I have a drill down navigation app with three levels of UIViewControllers.
In each view controller, I have a UITextField where I am trying to subclass the UIKeyboard for  each.  My question is where to "set" notifications and "unset" them.

I have the notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

so it it best to set them in the viewDidLoad event? Or the viewWillAppear event?

And likewise for `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

I don't want to have multiple `keyboardWillShow:` events to be called as I drill down.

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you put these in the `init` and `dealloc` methods, as the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` will be called **every time the view appears or disappears**, which is unnecessary for registering/deregistering notifications.

Comment: viewDidUnload: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

Comment: Register in init, unregister in dealloc

Comment: depends on when you want to achieve what

Answer (score 5):

I'd nevertheless suggest you register as observer in `viewWillAppear` and unregister in `viewWillDisappear` since `viewDidUnload` is called only when memory has to be freed, meaning `viewDidLoad` get called much more often than `viewDidUnload` and then you might have the problem of getting the same notification more than once.